Next-auth Google Authentication Issue on Localhost:3001 - "Access Blocked" Error
I'm encountering an issue with Next-auth Google authentication on my localhost development setup. I have separate instances for the admin side (localhost:3000) and client side (localhost:3001) of my e-commerce website.
The problem specifically occurs when I attempt Google authentication on the client side (localhost:3001). I'm receiving an error message stating "access blocked."
Callback URLs:
Admin Side: http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google
Client Side: http://localhost:3001/api/auth/callback/google
Next-auth Configuration:
Admin Side localhost:3000:
// Admin Side Configuration
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET
    }),
  ],
  // Other configurations...
})


Client Side (localhost:3001)
// Client Side Configuration
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET
    }),
  ],
  // Other configurations...
})


I've verified that the GOOGLE_ID and GOOGLE_SECRET environment variables are correctly set for both environments.
The Google Developer Console has the correct callback URLs configured for both localhost:3000 and localhost:3001.
enter image description here

Actually, if I'm understanding your screenshot, you're getting an error that says "If you are a developer click here for details". What are the details? Also, it says "Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch". Are you telling Google to redirect to localhost?

The redirect uri is used by the authorization server to identify where it is allowed to return the authorization code to.
They are configured in your project on google cloud console under your web application credentials.

If you click on the link "error details" in the image you have shown it will tell you exactly what redirect uri your application is sending from and what you need to add in the console configuration for your app.

Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error. Part 2 server sided web applications.

Google Oauth: error redirect_uri_mismatch the javascript origin Quick Fix.


